# How do we express the degree of a body's temperature from low to high when talking about illness?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [In everyday English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fever), people usually use **fever** to talk about a very
> high temperature. If someone's temperature is just high, they say that
> someone **has a temperature** rather than **has a fever**: He stayed home from
> school because he had a temperature.

Your child's forehead feels a bit warm, according to dictionaries, it's not correct to say "**you have a fever**".

**How do we express the degree of a body's temperature from low to high when talking about illness?**

**Can we say these to express the degree from low to high?**

-**you have a little temperature**: I am not sure it's ok to say that because "**temperature**" is a countable noun and "**little**" doesn't go with countable nouns

-**you have a bit of a temperature**

-**you have a high temperature**

-**you have a little fever**: I am not sure it's ok to say that because "**fever**" is a countable noun and "**little**" doesn't go with countable nouns

-**you have a bit of a fever**

-**you have a high fever**

Comment: 'You have a bit of a temperature' or 'You're a bit feverish'.

Answer (score 3):

These examples are all fine and would be understood by most native speakers.

"You have a little temperature" is OK because in this case **temperature** is not countable, it's referring to the degree of fever. One can have a little temperature (fever) the same way one can have a little dirt on one's nose. You would not say you have "two fevers" unless you mean two separate occasions where you had a fever.

Another common expression is "*running a fever*."

> Cathy was running a fever so we kept her home from school.

The text you quoted is not really correct about fever versus temperature
and I disagree with the linked site. Fever can be and is used for both mild and high temperatures. It's easy to find examples.

When referring to a fever that is not high, you'll often hear the phrases "**slight fever**," "**mild fever**," or "**low-grade fever**." This is common usage, and not wrong at all.

Usually these mean a body temperature that's above normal, but below the threshold of concern, usually up to 101F or 38C.

The common term for a high fever is usually just **high fever** and usually means a fever that's high enough to be of serious medical concern, generally
above 102 to 103 F (39-40C.)

Medically, a fever is defined as a temperature above 100.4F/38C, but normal body temperature varies per person, and the ranges differ for children versus adults. These are guidelines, not hard rules.

Comment: "You have a little temperature" sounds very off to me (whereas "you have a temperature" sounds okay but slightly old-fashioned). +1 for the rest, and I completely agree that the linked source is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

"You have a fever" is perfectly okay to use.

For instance, if you go to "https://medlineplus.gov/fever.html", which is the website of the U.S. National Library of Medicine, you will see various usages of the word fever, including "you have a fever".

As for the list of expressions you gave, it is okay to say "I have a temperature, I have a bit of a temperature" casually. But "in proper English" what you need to say is "I have a high temperature; I have a bit of a high temperature." or even better "I have an elevated temperature; I have a bit of elevated temperature."